# htop - show I/O wait percentage

Tags: linux, monitoring, htop

Is there a way to show I/O wait percentage in htop? I can't find a way how to enable this. On the following link there is an example of the functionality I need (the "Avg:" row): http://www.concept47.com/austin_web_developer_blog/sysadmin/something-cool-i-learned-about-htop/
But in my version of htop 2.0.2 I don't know how to enable this. I know that I can get this info from iotop and similar tools but I would like to have this info in htop.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Press <kbd>F2</kbd>, go to *AVailable Meters*, then select *CPU Average* or just *CPU* ( depending on version/distribution you are using. Add it to your view and place it where you like.
In the configuration dialog, navigate to the section you have added ( *Left column* / *Right column* ) and hit Space to toggle through the available types. The *type* you are looking for is *Text*.

#### Update

Additionally you might have to enable *Detailed CPU time (System/IO-Wait/Hard-IRQ/Soft-IRQ/Steal/Guest)* option which can be found in the <kbd>F2</kbd> menu, then *Display options*.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that I can change the display type using the Space key.

Comment: CPU Average is not the same as iowait.

Comment: "Detailed CPU time" gave me what I wanted.

Comment: @OrangeDog, you are, of course, 100% correct. CPU average is not the same as iowait. But, if you follow Thomas' instructions, set the "type" of the "CPU Average" meter to "text" and enable "Detailed CPU time" then the meter will show you text percentages for all the different CPU times, including io-wait.